# How can i get Abi from the byteCode using ethersjs i am using following code:-

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, abi

Its not working for me

const byteCode = await provider.getCode(address);
const AABBI = ethers.utils.Interface.parse(byteCode).abi;
console.log("AAABBBIII", AABBI);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

normally you can not extract the ABI from the bytecode as for instance the bytecode only includes function signatures.

If the contract has been verified, you can query the ABI on etherscan like this

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS&apikey=API_KEY
```

Hope it helps!